# Dedicated Button or Input Device to send Ctrl+Alt+Delete

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, ctrl-alt-delete

I know it's not possible to send Ctrl+Alt+Del with software-based methods (AutoHotkey, etc), but is there some way to do it hardware wise? Maybe a dedicated "Ctrl+Alt+Delete" USB button, like the "That Was Easy" button? I've seen [keyboards with a dedicated Ctrl+Alt+Delete button](http://gizmodo.com/5051024/hps-wireless-comfort-keyboard-has-emergency-ctrl-alt-del-key) so it must be possible somehow.

Comment: Most keyboards with macro keys have the capability to be programmed via software.  Outside of physically building your keyboard what you want isn't possible, without software, that defines the behavior of the keyboard's macro key

Comment: It depends on why you would like to press Ctrl+Alt+Del. If you are looking to open taskmanager, AutoHotKey could do this via 'Run taskmgr'